# jQuery Form Builder configure fine uploader

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader, formbuilder

How can I configure fine uploader as part of jQuery Form Builder? I create a form like this:

```
$('#fb-render').formRender({
  dataType: 'json',
  formData: data
});
```

data:

```
[{ 
  "type": "file", 
  "subtype": "fineuploader", 
  "label": "File Upload", 
  "className": "form-control", 
  "name": "file-"
}]
```

When I try to load file I get an error:

> POST http://localhost:4135/upload 404 (Not Found)
>   [Fine Uploader 5.14.2] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

[Loader looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heq99.png)

I need to stop file loading to endpoint "servername/upload". File should be sended to another address with all other fields. When i press submit button. I just need to stop loading while attachment and add some validations. I have read documentation, but in documentation it works separately from jquery Form Builder. Maybe i'm not got smth.

Comment: That error means that you've told the `formRender` to expect a JSON response, yet the actual response format is the HTML of your 404 error page. You need to debug why that is being returned. I'd suggest checking the path is correct.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan I know. The problem is: i need to stop loading to http://localhost:4135/upload just when i attach some file and save it inside fileLoader. And use when send the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure **fineuploader** in **formbuilder** or **formrender** using the **`controlConfig`** option. See the documentation here:
https://formbuilder.online/docs/formBuilder/controls/

Example(from official gitter chatroom of formbuilder): 
https://gitter.im/kevinchappell/formBuilder?at=5a018fe0f7299e8f5380acb4

```
controlConfig: {
   'file.fineuploader': {
     js: '/path/to/jquery.fine-uploader.min.js',
     css: '/path/to.css',
     handler: '/path/to/handler.php',
     // other fine uploader configuration options here
   }
 }
```

To prevent upload to `servername/upload` on choosing file, you can use the **`autoUpload`** option of **fineuploader**. See the documentation here:
 https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#autoUpload

Working Sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/qzTaNQZCvWHRlMm2hIU7?p=preview

Comment: You should mention [`autoUpload`](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#autoUpload) option available in fineuploader